# VBA - Delete rows that have the same ID and based on a Date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a VBA macro in order to delete rows that have the same ID **AND** contains a date before 01/01/2015. Please see the screenshot :  (red rows have to be deleted).

[image: screenshot]

I have started to build the following macro :

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'***** Variables declaration *****
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim EventDate As String
Dim Col As New Collection
Dim itm
Dim i As Long
Dim CellVal As Variant

'***** Find the last row *****
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'***** Conditional Formatting for Statut *****
For i = 2 To LastRow
    CellVal = Sheets("DataSet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

For Each itm In Col
    Debug.Print itm
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it only lists the different IDs and I don't know how to select the rows I want to delete.

Could you advise?

Thank you,
Damien

Comment: Your current code is not doing anything with regards to your question. Can you elaborate what you mean by same ID and have you tried recording a macro to delete duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store the row number `i` when finding a row to delete?

```
Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34), i
```

Actually, you're half way through. In that loop, determine if the ID and date match your pattern, and if so, store the rownumber. Then in a second loop, **looping from end to start (step -1)**, delete each row in the collection.

**Edit:**
Keep things simple. Do not use references to objects, but objects. "Make it work, make it right, make it fast" - in that order. This is what remains from your code when it does what is necessary:

```
  For Row = 2 To LastRow
     CellDate = CDate(S.Cells(i, 2).Value)
     If (CellDate < TestDate) Then
        If Not D.Exists(S.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
           D.Add S.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Else  ' is duplicate!
           willdeleted.Add Row
        End If
     End If
  Next Row

  For Row = willdeleted.Count To 1 Step -1
     Rows(willdeleted(i)).EntireRow.Delete
  Next Row
```

And do NOT use a Dictionary for the row numbers (willdeleted)! A simple list will do, either an Array() or a Collection. Dictionaries do not keep the order in which elements were added. The list of rownumbers to delete must be sorted, from lowest to highest, in order to be able to delete rows from the bottom of the table up.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of code and added codes of mine. Please examine codes and please say what you think. if you this couldnt not solve your problem, please give more information.

```
    Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '***** Variables declaration *****
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim EventDate As String
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CellVal As Variant
    Dim CellObj As Range


    'to check if cell exist in list earlier
    Dim D As Dictionary
    ' if same key exist in list then add it to willbedeleted list
    Dim willdeleted As Dictionary
    Dim S As Worksheet
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    Dim CellDate As Date
    Dim TestDate As Date

    '***** Find the last row *****
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set S = Worksheets("Dataset1")
    Set D = New Dictionary
    Set willdeleted = New Dictionary


    TestDate = CDate("01/01/2015")

    '***** Conditional Formatting for Statut *****
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Set CellObj = S.Cells(i, 1)

        On Error Resume Next

        CellDate = CDate(CellObj.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        If (CellDate < TestDate) Then
            If (Not D.Exists(CellObj.Value)) Then
               D.Add CellObj.Value, CellObj
            Else
               willdeleted.Add CellObj.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True), CellObj
            End If
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i


    a = willdeleted.Items
    For i = 0 To willdeleted.Count - 1
        CellObj = a(i)
        Debug.Print "#" & CellObj.Row & " row deleted.. : " & CellObj.Value & ", " & CellObj.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Rows(CellObj.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: I had written these codes on the purpose of understanding easily. Becase whom ask this question may have been started macro programming just newly.